# Other than large cardinal height, do all transitive models of ZFC differ only in how "wide" power sets are?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

There are two basic ways that I am familiar with generating different transitive models of ZFC:

1. Starting with the empty set, and iterating the power set construction to different heights.
2. Playing around with the what the power set construction is to begin with, by changing which first-order-undefinable subsets of sets we consider to "exist."

I have heard Joel David Hamkins say that the first property determines how "tall" a model is, whereas the second property determines how "wide" it is. The main question I have is if these are the only two basic degrees of freedom with which we have to create transitive models of ZFC.

In other words: clearly we can add more large cardinals and make it "taller", and clearly we can remove undefinable subsets and make it "narrower" and closer to something like $L$. Is that all we can do?

Of course there are slight variations on this idea - once the model is "narrow enough," we can also make it "shorter" than it otherwise could be. Likewise, I would guess we can probably have "lumpy" models which are "wider" in some parts than others - maybe they agree with $L$ up to some point and then start admitting undefinable subsets beyond that. But at the end of the day, we are still basically playing around with the same two basic ideas of varying how many undefinable subsets exist when you take the power set, and varying how many times you want to iterate the power set operation. Does that basically summarize all of the things we can do when creating a model of ZFC?

To attempt to put question on rigorous footing: Can we completely characterize a transitive model of ZFC by

1. the "length" of what the model thinks is the "cumulative hierarchy," expressed as an ordinal, and
2. the extent to which the power set operation admits or leaves out undefinable subsets at each stage?

Comment: Well, under reasonable hypotheses - which aren't much stronger than what's needed for the question to make sense in the first place - we can get more-than-continuum-many transitive models of ZFC of the same height. Consequently, we get two non-isomorphic but elementarily-equivalent transitive models with the same height. This seems to give a negative answer to any version of the question I can think of.

Comment: That is an interesting point (and I've edited my question to refer to transitive rather than just well-founded models, every well-founded model is isomorphic to a transitive one). But are you saying these things can arise from something beyond just playing with the power set operation? For instance, if $\kappa$ is the first inaccessible cardinal, we can look at $V_\kappa$ and $L_\kappa$. These have the same height but differ only in how "wide" they are. Similarly, there are uncountably many models in between, which have some intermediate level of non-constructable sets. (1/2)

Comment: No, I'm saying that "playing with the power set operation" is a much looser description than "the extent to which the power set operation admits or leaves out undefinable subsets at each stage" (although each is of course quite informal). Obviously two transitive models of ZFC which agree about powersets and have the same height are isomorphic (indeed literally equal).

Comment: But is there some kind of model that one can build which doesn't involve just varying the height and the amount of non-constructable sets in this way, and without losing transitivity? (2/2)

Comment: (Also, in my previous comment you don't actually need any additional hypotheses. Let $N$ be a "sufficiently large" forcing extension of a c.t.m. $M$ in which cardinalities and the continuum are preserved. Then $N$ has, from its perspective, more than continuum many non-isomorphic parameter-definable inner models, and so $N$ thinks it has non-isomorphic parameter definable elementarily-equivalent inner models. This is sufficiently absolute that it remains true in $V$.)

Comment: "is there some kind of model that one can build which doesn't involve just varying the height and the amount of non-constructable sets in this way, and without losing transitivity?" I don't really understand this question. Two transitive models with the same height that agree about powersets are literally the same. On the other hand, we can have elementarily equivalent transitive models with the same height which are not isomorphic, so merely paying attention to the "coarse behavior" of the powerset operation isn't going to be enough. What is left unanswered by this?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I get what you're saying, but I don't get how this leads to a "third degree of freedom" beyond "height" and "width." It seems to me that two different models of the same height will differ *only* in their view of what powersets are, as you said above (right?). Also, another way to look at the same difference is that these two models will be two different subsets of $V$, and differ only in which undefinable sets "exist" (right?). Thus, these two notions are the same: we change which undefinable sets exist by changing how the power set operation works. Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: Yes, there is only height and width. I'm not saying there's a third dimension, I thought that your phrase "the extent to which the power set operation admits or leaves out undefinable subsets at each stage" (or "varying how many undefinable subsets exist when you take the power set") was interpreting width in a more-restrictive fashion (not looking at *which* definable sets are included, but simply "how many" in some sense). I think we might have been talking past each other, I'm sorry!

Comment: Ah ok! Glad I got the right view of it then. If you wanted to make an answer I'd accept it; also very curious if you get the same thing in pure ZF without AC.

Comment: Yup, AC isn't needed. (There is a relevant statement where AC is relevant, namely two transitive models of ZFC are isomorphic if the have the same ordinals and sets of ordinals, but this is much weaker than what you're asking about.) I don't have time at the moment, but I'll add an answer later today.